# Allow curlftpfs though iptables firewall, how?

Tags: ftp, iptables, port

I'v allowed FTP ports 21 and 20 which then allows me to connect to my FTP server via "ftp" command, but I still can't get curlftpfs to work.

What ports does curlftpfs all use?
Or is their something else I have to do with iptables to allow curlftpfs?

```
curlftpfs -v 10.10.10.1 /ftp1/ -o user=user:pass
```

I get this in the log when I try to do "ls -l" in /ftp1/
http://drp.ly/13573T

I uploaded the log to that site since it would look very messy here

I use these rules to allow FTP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like curlftpfs is using pasv mode. You need to either force active mode, or `modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp` to allow pasv connections through.

To force active mode:

`curlftpfs -oftp_port=- myserver.example.com /mnt/my_ftpfs_mountpoint`

Make sure your firewall also accepts both incoming and outgoing traffic on port 20. Port 21 is outgoing only.

Comment: How would I force active mode with curlftpfs? (I looked though the man page but they don't say)
Also how would doing 'modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp' help? It's a firewall issue I though... since when I allow everything though the firewall it works.

Comment: BTW I ran 'modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp' but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Mint: From the man page (http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/curlftpfs.1/) use the -o ftp_port=$server_address option. also one of the two modprobe's (mine and Warner's) should have worked what distro are you on?

Comment: Im using Debian Lenny

Comment: huh, weird, i don't have a debian system, but works fine on my ubuntu boxes. Check your IPTABLES rules against the ones here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-passive-ftp-is-not-working/

Comment: Ah right, ftp_port worked. I'm missing a few rules looking at that site, so ill add some, thanks!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clean-up, Zypher!

Answer (score 1):

The `ip_nat_ftp` kernel module needs to be loaded if support is not compiled into the kernel.

Try:

`/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp`

Comment: No that didn't fix it, I put a log of the firewall while I tried to connect